# Delete array item for empty keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
[4] => Array
    (
        [label] => Politics
        [value] => politics
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [label] => 
        [value] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [label] => Sports
        [value] => sports
    )
```

I want delete this block

```
[5] => Array
    (
        [label] => 
        [value] => 
    )
```

So, I want delete process for empty array key or value.

Thanks.

Comment: what if `label`  or `value` contain `0` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : Remove object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573313/php-remove-object-from-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(array('label' => "" ,'value' => ''),array('label' => 'test','value' => 'tset2'));
    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if(empty($val['label']) ||  empty($val['value']) )
        {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array) ;
    echo "</pre>";
```

i think this code will help you

Comment: Thanks so much, this is awesome.

Comment: For big arrays it's better to use built in functions instead of iterating with foreach because they work significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can slice the element that you want to delete. Please refer link: [Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Comment: But, emtpy arrays is variable. It's not certain.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_filter($your_table);
```

http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-filter.php

I used this when i had the same problem with empty values in array

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to `''` filter,

```
$new = array_filter($entry, function ($var) {
    return ($var['label'] !== '' || $var['value'] !== '' );
});

print '<pre>';
print_r($new);
print '</pre>';
```

**Edit:** To `null` filter

```
$new = array_filter($entry, function ($var) {
    return ($var['label'] !== null || $var['value'] !== null );
});

print '<pre>';
print_r($new);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: The issue is still same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-filter.php) function.

For this array structure:

```
$arr = [
    [
        'label' => 'Politics',
        'value' => 'politics'
    ],
    [
        'label' =>'',
        'value' => ''
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Sports',
        'value' => 'sports'
    ],
];
```

This code would delete any element that doesn't have a label or a value:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function ($e) {
   return ($e['label'] || $e['value']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing something like the following pseudo-code

```
foreach (array_keys as key) {

   if  (empty(array[key][label])==true)
      unset(array[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all those sub-arrays that have all null, empty or false values you can use `array_filter` with a callable `array_filter`.

```
$data = 
[
    [
        'foo' => null,
        'bar' => 'big'    
    ],
    [
    ],
    [
        'baz' => 'fat',
        'bat' => 'mama'
    ],
    [
        'man' => '',
        'qux' => null,
        'quux' => false
    ]
];

$data = array_filter($data, 'array_filter');

var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'foo' => NULL,
    'bar' => 'big',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'baz' => 'fat',
    'bat' => 'mama',
  ),
)
```

Using array_filter without a callback will discard elements equal to FALSE.  (`(bool) array()` is false.)